# Why is 'be' sometimes the auxiliary verb for the present perfect?

Tags: english, french, perfect, auxiliary-verbs

1. Why do  [these 16 verbs](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/etreverbs_2.htm) require *être* as the auxiliary verb, to form the *passé composé*  in French?

2. [Abbreviated as DMPRRS, these 6 (of the 16)](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/etreverbs_3.htm)  are ambitransitive. When transitive, their auxiliary verb reverts to the usual *avoir*. Why? 
Are there explanations more detailed than John McWhorter [PhD  Linguistics (Stanford)](https://americanstudies.columbia.edu/people/john-h-mcwhorter)'s  beneath?

---

Source:  [*Our Magnificent Bastard Tongue* (2009)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Our-Magnificent-Bastard-Tongue-History/dp/1592404944). 
**[p. 102 Bottom]**

Learn a European language, including any Germanic language but Swedish, and note that quite often, while most verbs form their past perfect with the verb *have*—*Ich habe gesprochen* (“I have spoken”)—a good little bunch do it with the verb *be*, too—*Ich bin gekommen* (“I ‘am come’ ”). Just like in Old English: *Learning had fallen away* was “Learning *was* fallen away”: *Lār āfeallen wæs*.
  Marking some verbs with be instead of have is a matter of being explicit about a certain nuance: in the perfect, the verbs marked with *be* refer, technically, to a state rather than an action; i.e., something that *be*s. When you say you have arrived, you mean that you have now achieved the state of being there: “I’m here, so let’s get started.” On the other hand, when you talk about how you raked leaves this afternoon, you usually are getting across that you *per-*

**[p. 103]**

*formed* the action of raking leaves, not that you have achieved the *state* of having raked the leaves and are now ready to have your picture taken.
  We English speakers think, “Well, yeah . . .” but hardly feel it necessary to split that hair. The other Germanic languages do split it—and Old English did.
  But something strange started happening in Middle English, as usual; now it was the *be*-perfect that was falling away (like autumn leaves). By Shakespeare, *be* is used with only a few verbs

> (“And didst thou not, when she was gone downstairs, desire me to be no more so familiarity with such poor people?” *Henry IV, Part II*, II, i, 96)

and today, it lingers on only in a frozen form such as *The autumn leaves now are gone*. Even there, you may well have thought of *gone* as an adjective (*The leaves are red, The leaves are gone*), and in any case you can also say *The autumn leaves **have** gone*, which, in this case of the grand old Old English *be*-perfect, they have, as always in English.

**[p. 148 Bottom]** [[The content is also mooted on English SE]](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/3415/50720).

And forget our processing that when we *have e-mailed* something, an action has been performed while when we *have left*, a state has arisen in which we *are gone*. When using the perfect, Old English speakers used *be* instead of *have*, with a bunch of verbs that referred more to how things ended up than an event happening. Apparently to us today, “states, schmates”—everything is an action.

---

Source: [*What Language Is* (2011)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/159240720X), [p. 27 Top](https://books.google.com/books?id=xFQbHnvLonkC&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=%22robust+in+its+germanic+relatives%22&source=bl&ots=o61SulUblG&sig=mqVqkEkgOK5-LwTrwsKB6tnmJrs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi51o6vouHbAhXCmVkKHQ2FDeAQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22robust%20in%20its%20germanic%20relatives%22&f=false).

Or, what part of speech is *gone* in *She is gone*? Call it an 
adjective—and explain why you can't say *a gone dog* as you can 
say *a brown dog*. *She is gone* is English's wan gesture toward 
something robust in its Germanic relatives, in which a whole 
group of verbs take *be* instead of *have* in the past, because they 
describe something that is more how you are than what you 
did. To be gone is just that, to *be* gone. Sure, it is also technically 
to "have" exerted the action of leaving, but we think more read-ily of the result of the leaving, that one is in the state of being 
gone. Thus just as French has *Il est allé*, "He is gone," German 
has *Er ist gegangen*. All of the other Germanic languages have 
the equivalent, or almost all (what's up with you, Swedish?). 
English crudely forces *have* on every verb, and while Swedish 
does, too, that's just one coarseness, as if it happened not to 
learn to put a napkin in its lap but still went about in double- 
breasted suits and cultivated orchids. English, in comparison, 
just-the-facts-ma'am across the board, is Cro-Magnon.

Comment: This is a regional feature of some European languages, (so is using the verb for "to have" to make past/perfect tenses in fact.) So you will also find examples of it in German, and as mentioned in some (archaic) English usage.

Comment: Please [edit] this to fix the title. You're not asking about the mnemonic, you're asking about a set of words.

Comment: @curiousdannii Thanks. Would you please advise of a more helpful title? I used DR MRS VANDERTRAMP because I don't know how else to cite these 16 especial verbs.

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit That page calls them "être verbs". If you're asking about English rather than French then you'd need to establish that they are a verb class in English.

Comment: Italian also has the _ho_ vs. _sono_ contrast. I wonder if that's the same phenomenon.

Answer (score 1):

DR & MRS VANDERTRAMP are **verbs that deal with state, movement, and direction**. They are also used intransitively (without a direct object; e.g., *Je suis sorti.*, 'I went out.').

You can see the difference notably when you consider that if some of these same verbs are used transitively or ditransitively, then « être » is no longer the copula. Instead, those verbs then take « avoir » as their copula (e.g., *J'ai sorti les poubelles*, 'I took out the trash.').

Consider the following:

- I was birthed. (vs) *I have birthed. (vs) I have birthed two kids.
- I was outed. (vs) *I have outed. (vs) I have outed the cheaters.

The examples won't match up exactly  cross-linguistically, but the general idea is there.

According to Fagyal et al. (2006), "The combination of the auxiliary verb...and the past participle [in French] might have originally retained the possessive meaning of 'to have' [from Latin], so that *epistolas scriptas habeo* might have meant 'I have written some letter' or 'I have some letters that were written'."

It's possible that latin roots referring to possesives when using 'have' may be attributing to the need in French for a secondary PAST AUX (« être ») for statives.

Comment: Hopefully the additional information helps somewhat. It's likely an historical change based on Latinate roots.

Comment: Thank you. I deleted my earlier, now outmoded (pun intended) comment.

Answer (score 1):

The "why" of it is essentially a question of whether the participle refers back to the subject. The *être* verbs all refer to a changed state of the subject — which is particularly obvious with *naître*, *mourir*, *tomber* and *rester*.

Now you might ask: why just those thirteen verbs? Aren't there many more that can be construed to involve a change of the subject's state, and hence require "be" rather than "have"? Why is "I have grown up" *J'ai grandi*, not **Je suis grandi*?

That's a reasonable question. In fact, there are languages that are more consistent about be/have, such as Danish: *Jeg **er** vokset op* "I have ('am') grown up", as opposed to *Jeg **har** set noget* "I have seen something". It must have been the case with French at some point as well, before *avoir* began to take over, so that only thirteen *être* verbs remained in the end, most likely because they were common enough for their existing perfect forms to survive as set phrases.

Comment: Danish might be more consistent, but it's still not as easy as transitivity vs non-transitivity. For example, "have" tends to be used for the experiential pp, whereas "være" tends to be used for the "resulting state". "Han er rejst", he has travelled, as in he has gone travelling, but "han har rejst meget", he has travelled a lot.

Comment: @dainichi Very similar to _go_ in English there: “He is gone” (= he is no longer here) vs. “He has gone on many trips” (= experiential). Note that “Han er rejst” with no PP to indicate the goal of his travels usually does not mean “he has gone travelling”, but rather “he has departed”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, similar on the surface, but not so sure deeper down. In the "depart" sense, rejse is always with "være", PP or not, e.g. "Han er rejst til Kina", whereas *"He is gone to China" is not standard, AFAIK.